# JSF javax.servlet.ServletException: duplicate Id for a component wdForm:j_id205

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my application, in one of the pages I have several data ouput and data iteration components. This page contains several popup model panels as well. Every component is created with their unique ID's. The page contains several independent forms to submit the components. The mentioned page is my main page in the application. When I enter the page, it redirects me to the main page as mentioned. Initially when I enter the page, it works properly. However, when I walk through other pages and come back to the main page I encounter the "duplicate Id for a component" error. I tried to solve this problem by googling and reading other forms but I couldn't obtain a clear answer. How could I solve it, what criteria should I consider throughly. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you in deep...

Comment: You should set IDs for your components so that you don't get generated ones (like j_id205). Then you will be able to identify the component that is causing this issue. Then please post the corresponding xhtml fragment.

Comment: Are you using `binding` anywhere in the page? If so, does it point to a session scoped bean? That's one of the most common causes. It's at least not possible to give an answer based on the information provided so far. This can have many possible causes and you didn't post an SSCCE at all.